# Проверка загружаемого файла на размер и формат

Tags: python, django

Загружаю изображение при помощи generics.ListCreateAPIView. Как лучше организовать проверку файла на размер и формат?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Если под форматом понимается тип файла, то это можно сделать с помощью валидатора на [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.FileField). Например,

```py
def is_json_file(value):
    if value.content_type != 'application/json' \
            or not value.name.endswith('.json'):
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            'Not a JSON file', code='content_type'
        )


class ImportJSONForm(forms.Form):
    content_json = forms.FileField(
        label='JSON contents',
        validators=[is_json_file]
    )
```

Ограничить размер загружаемых файлов можно с помощью настройки [FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE).